# Guide to installing Ubuntu onto a system with Windows 8 Preinstalled

Tags: installation, windows, windows-8

I'm interested in installing Ubuntu onto my Asus laptop which is running Windows 8. I'm a bit nervous. What if the installation goes wrong? I want Ubuntu to be my default operating system. If it messes up will I be able to go back to Windows 8?

Comment: You don't have to be worry about nothing in the computing world, just do a back up and put your hands in work. You can find useful information [here](http://askubuntu.com/q/6328/62483), but I recommend to read [this post](http://askubuntu.com/q/221835/62483) as you have Windows 8, there will be interest things to learn.

Answer (score 0):

why not use dual booting, this means you can select either windows or ubuntu on startup so you can allways go back to windows if the installation goes sour or you muck up something while using ubuntu, the installer is fairly easy to understand so there's next to no chance of messing the install up.

Oh yea, ALWAYS BACKUP...

Info Page About Installing onto a Win8 PC: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI

---

And don't be nervous, Linux is a lot easier than people make out, granted you have to get use to the odd way it does stuff, but it's really nothing to get stressed about.

Good luck  =D